# JSDoc setting up?

Tags: javascript, jsdoc

I am not that good at computers but am trying to use JSDoc for one of my projects,

The tutorial to get it up and running is here

http://usejsdoc.org/about-jsdoc3.html

I have downloaded the program from github, but now do not understand what I have to do. I have a bunch of files in a folder and dont know how to get it actually running for my project.

Could someone please give me a step by step instruction on how to actually get JSDoc working, how do I set it up, how do I use it etc.

I know this may be mundane to some of you, but hey we all gotta start somewhere right?

Answer (score 6):

Well, are you using windows or GNU/Linux?
First, you have to follow the default tags to markup your source code, identifying your classes, methods, parameters, etc...
After that, you download the file here: https://github.com/jsdoc3/jsdoc
Extract it and then go to folder jsdoc-master.

Inside it, you have a script called jsdoc (with no extension). Only you have to do is execute it pointing the whole path to your .js file you want to create a documentation like this: ./jsdoc your_class.js
Then, in a couple minutes you'll have the output inside the 'out' folder. Open the .html file and bang! You have your documentation working pretty good.

Right here you can find some common tags to use in your code (as comments): http://usejsdoc.org/

This solution is for Unix based system. But, there is another one using nodejs (that you can run with windows, Linux, mac, etc...). First, download the nodejs here: http://nodejs.org/

Then go to this website to take a look at the package jsdoc: https://npmjs.org/

Then, go back to your terminal (in any operating system after installed node) and type: npm install -g jsdoc
The option -g means globally, so you have inside the main folder of your node packages and they are available for whatever project you have and you don't need to install it again and again...

Finally, you can just use this command: jsdoc path/to/your/file.js

And that's it! I hope it helps you.

Answer (score 0):

Once you've extracted the file you downloaded off of github, navigate within the folder and run in a terminal:

```
./jsdoc
```

with the options you want.

If you want to display the help menu

```
./jsdoc --help
```

If you want to install the program on your system, assuming a mac or linux machine, use root user or `sudo`:

```
npm install --save -g [~/Downloads/jsdoc-3.2.2 or your path to the downloaded extracted files]
```